# JavaFX use "Labels" as menu items

Tags: java, javafx, menu, fxml

So I have a menu defined effectively as following:

```
<Menu fx:id="fileMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="openImageMI" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openFile" text="Open image file" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="saveFileMI" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveFile" text="Save excel file" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="quickSaveMI" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quickSave" text="Quick save excel file" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="chooseFileMI" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseSaveFile" text="Choose excel save file" />
        </items>
</Menu>
```

As you can see, 1 of my options opens an image file, and the other 3 open/save to excel files. I would like to have "Labels" above item 1 and item 2, sort of signifying different sections of the menu. I considered using Submenus but there aren't that many options in the menu so i didn't feel it was justified. I tried also doing stuff with `SeperatorMenuItem` but had no luck getting it to display any text.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: hmm ... something like a labeledSeparator? Not supported afaik, you'll have to roll your own

Comment: @kleopatra yeah i was thinking some kind of `CustomMenuItem`, containing a label. i'll then need to style it to not be highlighted when hovered over etc.